# Exporting 2d array into new file using C

Tags: arrays, c

I have been working on an assignment that requires me to read a file containing a list of names into a 2D array, and then to write the array to a new file. I am able to read the file into an array, and I am able to create a new file and export the names, but unfortunately it is not writing the names onto new lines and instead only writing the names over one another.

For example, I have the following names in names.txt:

> Sean
> Joe
> Steve
> Taka
> Kathy

However, in the new file it is only showing Kathy. How would I go about making sure that each name in the array is array is printed on a new line?

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* fp2;
    char nameArray[20][120], str[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char name[20];

    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    fp = fopen(name, "r");


    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        strcpy(nameArray[i], str);
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fp2 = fopen("newNames.txt", "wb");
        fwrite(nameArray[i], sizeof(char), 5, fp2);
    }
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        printf("%s\n", nameArray[n]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reopening the file inside the for loop (without even closing it)... move that line up:

```
fp2 = fopen("newNames.txt", "wb");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{        
   fwrite(nameArray[i], sizeof(char), 5, fp2);
}
```

And don't forget to close it after you are done: `fclose(fp2);`

Answer (score 0):

One additional key step for functions  like fopen() is to always verify the return before attempting to use its return value.    And if return fails handle the error.  Eg, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fp2 = fopen("newNames.txt", "wb");
    fwrite(nameArray[i], sizeof(char), 5, fp2);
}
size_t n;
for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    printf("%s\n", nameArray[n]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

}

Should be arranged as:

```
fp2 = fopen("newNames.txt", "wb");
if(fp2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fwrite(nameArray[i], sizeof(char), 5, fp2);
    }
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", nameArray[n]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
else
{
     printf("Failed to open file.  Exiting.");
     return -1;
}
```